# How use a group of scrum task as a template in Visual Studio Team Services online

Tags: task, azure-devops, scrum

I do have a common group of scrum sub tasks in my project. For instance:
Create a Model, Controller and View for Details, Create, Edit, Delete and List.

[image]

This is a very common group of tasks. Several features should have it be done.

I did not found a "copy paste", bulk duplicate items nor a template which can hold sub-items.

How can I create this group of tasks and copy all features?

Comment: What's the tasks be used for? Do you mean build task? We could save a build definition as template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export them to Excel and then use Excel to create copy for them. Following is the basic steps:

1. Create a query for your work item groups and save the query:
   [image]
2. Open Excel\Team panel, click "New List" and then connect to your team project, select the query created in Step 1, you will get the group of the tasks:
   [image]
3. Copy and paste these tasks in the same sheet, and then select the new copied tasks and click "Publish" button:
   [image]
4. You will see the ID for these copied work items display in the work sheet after publishing and you can also check them from VSTS web portal.

Refer to this link for more information: [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel).